# lightning spinner not working

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, promises

I'm using a spinner to indicate there is something loading. I added this in the template:

```
<div if:true={pendingAction}>
    <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading"></lightning-spinner>
</div>
```

This is the code for pendingAction:

```
@api get pendingAction() {
    return this._pendingAction;
}

set pendingAction(promise) {
    this._pendingAction = promise;
    promise.finally(() => {
        this._pendingAction = null;
    });
}
```

So the deal is I use it by assigning to pendingAction, an apex call, so for instance:

```
handleSearchProms(){
    let filterData = this.template.querySelector('c-lwc-filter').exportData();
    this.pendingAction = this.getSellerId(filterData.value).then(r => {
        console.log('seller id:' + r);
        this.sellerId = r;
        this.getSellerProms().then(r =>{
            this.sellerPromotions = JSON.parse(r).results;
        })
    });
}
```

For some reason, the spinner doesn't appear. And in the same component, I call another apex method:

```
getItems(){
    this.pendingAction = getItemsInPromotion({sellerId : this.sellerId, promotionId : this.selectedPromotion.promotion_id, params : this.params}).then(r => {
        console.log('r: ', r);
        this.updateResults(r);
    }).catch(e =>{
        showError(e, this);
    })
}
```

In this case it is worse, as the spinner appears, but only AFTER the data from apex is loaded, and it gets stuck there. Any idea why?

EDIT: this is the updateResults method in case anyone needs to know what that is, what it does is assign the results, nothing more.

```
updateResults(r){
    cache.set(r.items);
    this.items = r.items;
    this.pagingResults = r.api.paging;
    console.log(this.pagingResults); 
}
```

Comment: Make `pendingAction` tracked, not API (simply remove the `@api` annotation). It isn't valid for a component to modify its own API properties.

Comment: I did, but the spinner still gets stuck after the data is loaded. I'm using it the same way as in other situations, I don't know why its happening!

Comment: The promise approach is clever, but maybe is causing more issues than it is worth? Instead simply explicitly set the property true before invoking processing and back to false when the processing completes (e.g. in the imperative call promise handlers themselves)...

Comment: I understand. Just make it simpler and set a boolean, yeah. I'll try that and see if it solves it

Comment: @PhilW yeah, that did the trick. Thanks!